# How to insert a special character into QMenu as a part of Title text?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmenu

I want to insert a special character '&' into a QMenu as a part of Titletext on windows with QT.

How can i do it?

If I put this character into a QMenu as Titletext through QMenu::setTitle() function, 
then I can not see the special character.

The special character is just missing there.

I know that this special character '&' is normaly used for setting shortcut.

But i need to insert this character into QMenu as a part of Titletext.

Comment: Use two `&&` instead of one `&`  it will show as one.

Comment: `ui->menu->setTitle("aaa&&bbb"); //menu text will be: aaa&bbb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it is not described in [QMenu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#details) documentation, but it is mentioned in [QMenuBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#details) detailed description:

> You can use "&&" to get a real ampersand in the menu bar.